# Debugging loops

Tags: eclipse, debugging, loops

For some current projects, I'm working with several data structures that are pretty large (in the area of 10K elements).  To be able to access this data in lists, I need to use loops and iterators, which can be a pain when the problem area is in the latter half of the list.

So I find myself spending alot of time with my finger on the F8 button in Eclipse's debugger to loop through each element of an iterating loop.  This gets worse when have to step through that particular section several times to get an idea why the code is reacting a particular way.

If one has a general idea how many times a loop is to execute before a problem area is hit, is there a way to set a loop breakpoint to execute up to that point then pause?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use conditional breakpoints.

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_set_a_conditional_breakpoint%3F

Comment: done.  turns out you can't accept an answer till 10 min after its been asked.

Answer (score 5):

I believe there's a better way to do this, but you can create a trivial block of code in the loop that only executes at a certain iteration, and put the breakpoint inside of it.

```
if (loopIndex == 1000) {
  int number = 14;            //Break here
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I was originally considering as a solution, but just wanted to know if there was a better answer

Answer (score 1):

Using this as an example:

```
for(int i=0;i<10000;i++){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Set a breakpoint on the print line, then right click on it and select `Breakpoint Properties...`. From here you can set a condition to trigger the breakpoint. This is the similar to a conditional you would have in an if-statement. If you wanted to trigger the breakpoint when i equals 6000, check the `Conditional` box and try this: [image]